# 1980s novel about portal to alternate dimension with energy beings, sacrifice of sentient natives, computer leech

Tags: story-identification

An english-language sci-fi novel that I owned in the early 1980s, probably written no later than the late 1970s. I have plenty of details, I'm just not finding the result:

- Starts with the protagonist *in media res* as he's escaping from the organization he's been a trusted high executive (VP or similar) with. His name is something like "Carstairs"; his boss, with whom he's had a falling out, shares a name with a raptor, something like Hawke or Hawkesworth (I'm sure of that because it figures into a coded message he sends that alludes to birds of prey)
- He helped design the boss's security (including an escape tunnel) so he's able to escape with the help of a "computer leech" -- a pocket-sized device he's acquired that can remotely access computer systems. It has a glass-faced display though uses a voice interface. He also throws smoke and incendiary capsules during the escape to evade flying guard drones.
- The organization has built a gateway to a dimension of sentient energy beings. The humans can extract energy from their side, but can't send usable energy from our side to theirs. The beings need energy because their universe will (relatively) soon suffer from entropic collapse without it.
- The humans accidentally discover that unprotected sentient beings who go through the portal die and transfer usable energy across. They have access to a compliant, native sentient species who don't mind serving as fuel and being sent across to die.
- The protagonist develops a relationship with a native and discovers that they do value life, so he then opposes their killing and tries to stop it, causing the falling out.
- After he escapes, he meets up with a female ally, one of his boss's former lovers.

  > She's later killed by the boss's goons
- He disguises himself and attempts to reinfiltrate the organization (basically applying for his old job) so he can sabotage the portal. (No, it's not a particularly wise course of action.)
- At the final confrontation, he faces his former boss in the energy dimension. They're both wearing spacesuit-like outfits that allow them to survive there. He's rigged the portal to explode. It turns out his boss has anticipated much of this, and has promised the energy beings they can have the protagonist's life energy (by killing him).
- Then

  > he convinces the energy beings that the agreement isn't binding on him as a third-party, and that they should kill his boss instead, which they do. It ends with him choosing to live by heading back towards the portal to our universe, instead of waiting to die in the energy dimension after his bomb goes off.
- The monochromatic cover isn't very good and features an illustration of the bulky, Michelin Man/spacesuit-type protective outfit

Comment: Awesome description!

Comment: I bet the author had read Asimov's "The God's Themselves". There's enough similarity there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had an near-literal shower moment and remembered the book: *[Gateway to Limbo](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/5782815-gateway-to-limbo)* (1979) by Christopher Lampton. There's not too much detail online, but it's definitely the book; per the details from the Kirkus review on Goodreads:

- Protagonist's name is Allison Carstairs; he was research head and VP under the bad guy, Ian Hawkesworth, head of the General Cybernetics corporation.
- The alternate dimension is the Secondary Energy Plane, nicknamed "Limbo."
- The race being sacrificed are the natives of the planet Aerie, Aerians.
- You can judge my description of the book cover: "The monochromatic cover isn't very good and features an illustration of the bulky, Michelin Man/spacesuit-type protective outfit":

  [image: Book jacket of Gateway to Limbo by Chris Lampton]